# Coreos install stop on "Fetching user-data from datasource"

Tags: hyper-v, coreos

I try to install coreos on hyper-v on windows server 2008 r2.
I set up virtual machine, give it an `coreos.iso`, then `wget` my `cloud-config.yaml`
Then I try to `sudo coreos-install -d /dev/sda -c cloud-config.yaml` and it says

```
Checking availability of "local-file"
Fetching user-data from datasource of type "local-file"
```

And... that's all, it does no more

Here's my `cloud-config.yaml`

```
#cloud-config

hostname: dockerhost

coreos:
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start

users:
  - name: core
    ssh-authorized-keys: 
      - ssh-rsa somesshkey

  - groups:
      - sudo
      - docker
```

FIY i'm using [this tutorial](http://stevieholdway.tumblr.com/post/90167512059/coreos-bare-metal-iso-install-tutorial)

Comment: try running the command as `$ sudo bash -x coreos-install -d /dev/sda -c cloud-config.yaml` and take a look at the output

Comment: @BrianRedbeard I gracefully thank you for the help, it was our new proxy

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out
It was our proxy server, which I find out when I use an excellent command `bash -x` which gave me the full output

Command was proposed by @BrianReadbeard